# Adding groups as members to a Connections community through the API

Tags: ldap, ibm-sbt, ibm-connections

I am looking for a way to add a group as a member to community when I know the groupName (from the Directory Server).

When I add a group to a community through the UI I can pick from existings groups, but I have not found the API equivalent of this call yet.

Is does not seem to be a profile, entering the snx:userid

```
<snx:userid xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">AB16E3DF-D544-4984-94AE-FAAC7A5F2AA6</snx:userid>
```

To the profileservice endpoint:

```
https://CONNECTIONSHOST/profiles/atom/profile.do?userid=AB16E3DF-D544-4984-94AE-FAAC7A5F2AA6
```

Does not return a profile...

So the question is , how can I add a (LDAP) group as a member to a community when I don't have the sn:userid but only the groupname ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following
METHOD = POST
AUTHORIZATION = {BASIC}|{OAUTH}
CONTENT-TYPE application/atom+xml
URL PATTERN = communities/service/atom/community/members?communityUuid=${communityUuid}
METHOD POST

Where the communityUuid is the community's unique id

The payload should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
 xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" 
 xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">
<contributor>
<snx:userid>ID OF GROUP</snx:userid>
<snx:role>member</snx:role>
</contributor>
<category scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type" term="group"></category>
<snx:role component="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/activities">member</snx:role>
</entry>
```

Then replace the ID of Group with your group's ID, and then you will be able to add the group to the community.

Comment: Thanks Paul, how do I know the ID of a group, this seems a Connections specific ID ? Remember I only have access to the group informatie in de Directory (like DN, CN etc..)

Comment: it should be the uuid of the group.

Comment: the uuid of the group in the Directory Server ?

Comment: Yes the objectGUID is the GUID that is used as the group ID